# link ableton to traktor and let traktor be the master

Tags: ableton-live, traktor

Has anyone successfully get this scenario working?
I dj with traktor. I use timecoded vinyls/cds and i always mix live. No songs are premapped with cuepoints ets.. the only analysis traktor gets done is when loading the song in deck and that way it has "super" good knowledge of actual bpm. Now still want to be able to use my pitch faders on the vinyl/cdj ... aand.. this leads me to ableton link. While playing as described above id like ableton to LINK up with traktor and follow the tempo from traktor, that is, the tempo im controlling with pitch faders.
When doing that ableton should adjust all loops that its currently playing live so that i can mix them in as another, call it "spice" in the mix... all in time offcourse...
Is that Possible?
Kind regard

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible. but first, it's OS specific method. To achieve that, generally, you need to make the traktor outputing a midi clock and captured by ableton later.

**in traktor it should be like this:**

- Go to TRAKTOR's Preferences > MIDI Clock menu.
- Under MIDI Clock Settings, check the box Send MIDI Clock.

and ableton should capture that clock(with/without intermediary application)

this [Link](https://support.native-instruments.com/hc/en-us/articles/210300905-How-to-Sync-TRAKTOR-and-Ableton-Live) should help you more.

**and for the ableton part**:

if you want to make the song follows the tempo, make sure you warp each song(audio clip) according to it's own tempo. and it's automatically follows the master tempo.

how to warp audio clip? follow this [link](https://www.ableton.com/en/manual/audio-clips-tempo-and-warping/).

good luck